# Special Character in MySQL Table Name

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database which contains a table named "event-site". It has one column named "signature" and i want to select that particular column using MySQL lib in python. I tried "SELECT signature FROM event-site" and "SELECT signature FROM 'event-site'" (apostrophe around the table name as it contains special characters) but none seems to work. I always get the error that there is an error in the MySQL syntax and I should look near 'event-site'. Can somebody help me with the right syntax?

Comment: try to surrond "event-site" with ` characters

Comment: Use back quotes. SELECT signature FROM `event-site`